# Customize Transactional Emails - Get part of an order

Tags: invoice, email-templates, transactional

I'm trying to customize the transactional emails for new Order and new Invoice. For "New Invoice" I want to show something like this

For your Order from (date without time in european format) you will find our invoice for the consignment below:

```
    Totals(incl. Taxes):      € 13.97

            Incl. Tax 1:       19,00%     €0.31     €0.05
            Incl. Tax 2:        7,00%    €13.66     €0.89
```

Payable within 14 days. etc etc

So I only want to show the order total including the taxes and the taxes themselves. Is there a way to f.e. get the order object within the email template file, to be able to get all the infos out of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better using the Magento settings options already in place for this in the system area of your Magento admin area. So System > Configuration > Sales > Tax > Orders, Invoices, Credit Memos Display Settings

And then edit the settings you want from there. Hope this helps?

Comment: thanks, this pointed me in the right direction. This way I was able to solve another problem as well.